# placing hermetical packages on PCB and soldering

Tags: analog, soldering, packages, footprint

I stumbled upon some hermetically enclosed packaged - [Link](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/k8_a/k8.a.pdf).
The package has a small bulge/projection on the bottom. This makes the package leads basically float without contact with the PCB. How do we solder such pads on PCB ?. Also, this bottom extension, how is it placed on the PCB ? Will there a small hole or slot or such thing to house this bulge ?

The screenshot is as shown below -
[image: Component]

Comment: Is that from their service to package an IC you provide? Then I would say it is up to you to bend the leads.

Comment: It is already an IC. How do u furtehr package it ?

Comment: An IC is not really only the things you buy at digikey with the leads. The essential core of it is the silicon/saphire/whatever die, or you could have a miniature ceramic PCB with directly soldered/welded dies that you want to have packaged. Or some dies with bonding and potting together. And there are services that provide you just that packaging.

Comment: Could you kindly give me a link or something that can be a bit more informative please ?

Comment: Easiest solution is probably to specify a matching cutout in the PCB, so the part drops into the cutout.

Comment: Ceramic flatpack leads are meant to be trimmed and formed before final assembly. Also very important is to strip the gold flash in order to get a reliable joint.